# I call a method in class A and from class it works. But if I call the same method in class B I get error

Tags: android

> here is the method

```
public String testFile(int numofpunches, String filename,  int picture, int cancelpix){
    String string="";
    Boolean a;
    FILENAME = filename;
    try {
        FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename);
        try{
            int counter = fis.read( mIds, 0,numofpunches);
            fis.close();
            int i=0;
            while( i <counter ){
                if(mIds[i] == 'c'){
                    mThumbIds[i++] = picture; //R.drawable.crab;
                    string=string.concat("c");

                }else{

                    mThumbIds[i] = cancelpix; 
                    string=string.concat("x");


                    ImageView punchit =  (ImageView) 
findViewById(mypunches[i++]);

punchit.setImageResource(R.drawable.punchboxcancelled);




                }
            }
            String testfordone = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
            a= string.equals(testfordone.substring(0,numofpunches));
            if(a){
                return "done";
            }
        }catch (IOException e){


        }
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        try {//initialize
            String FILENAME = filename;
            FileOutputStream fos =  openFileOutput(FILENAME, 
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            string  = "cccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccccc";
            string.substring(0,numofpunches);

            try {
                fos.write(string.getBytes());
                fos.close();


                int counter = 0;
                while(counter < numofpunches ){

                    mThumbIds[counter++] =  picture; 

                }
            }catch(IOException err){

            }

        }catch(FileNotFoundException error){


        };

    }
```

> I call it from the same class (A) where this method is located.
>   Now I create a new class (PunchActivities) with the same method.
>   Import class PunchActivities in A
>   call the method as

```
PunchActivities pa = new PunchActivities();
String result = pa.testFile(all the required parameters);
```

> At runtime the program gets to

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename); in PunchActivities
```

> but then it gets back to class A with NullPointer error.
>   WHY????? anyone know the rules of android??

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
      punchit.setImageResource(R.drawable.punchboxcancelled);
```

Because in this class , you have not set the same xml as in the earlier class(in the setContentView() method in onCreate()). So this view in not find-able here.

Comment: The error pointed is at openFileInput(...) which is called before
punchit.setImageResource(R.drawable.punchboxcancelled).

Comment: I found out that I need to pass the path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Pass the Context as a parameter in your function and use `context.openFileInput(fileName)`. And same is for `openFileOutput(fileName)`.

I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Better u the following instead of  "FileInputStream fis = openFileInput(filename); in PunchActivities,"

Try this

```
FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(filename);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that I need to pass the path to the file.

Comment: If this is the solution, click the empty check box underneath the post's score to accept it.